# Shell Script Setting Executing time

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to set a time in shell script so that it runs automatically during the working hours and stop for set times and rerun again after the set times.

for example.

`if [ -d /tmp/test ] 
then 
    for dir in $(ls -d $DIR1/* | grep test)
    do
        ....
    done 
fi`

I want this to run and during the set time, lets say 1 pm to 3 pm, I want this to stop for during that hours and run again.

how can I write this in Shell Script?

my point is to run a single shell script fully automated..
it runs only ONCE processing all the necessary work during this ONE run.. but at the given time it should stop and rerun again.

how can I implement this inside of Shell Script?

Comment: Have you considered using cron? Please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: Don't do this: `for dir in $(ls -d $DIR1/* | grep test)` -- do this instead: `for dir in "$DIR1"/*test*/`

Comment: How long does one run of the script take?

Comment: it usually takes few hours  around 3 to 5 hours some times more

Answer (score 0):

Use cron (assuming the script will be run in a *nix OS)

Then you set in cron parameters of which hours of the day it can run in, and other fancy stuff.

(I'd research "cron tutorial" via web search)

Comment: isn't cron only for executing command? also i thought it cannot control when to stop and start again.. isn't it only for run certain amount of time?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the "at" command to schedule the execution of your script.

```
man at
```

You need to make sure though that the atd daemon is running, which on most systems should be included in the "atd" package. To start the atd daemon:

```
service atd start
```